# How can i send a notification between two types of users in a app un flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, calendar, android-calendar

Well, now im developing a calendar app un Flutter, but i don't know how can i link two types of users in it; Let me explain, the app should work more like this:

-The general user, named in the code "client" should be able to pick a date in the calendar and make a event with hour, day, month, etc.

-The admin user, named "admin" should be able to receive a notification about allow or decline the creation of this event.

Then, my problem is how can i make the system send the notification to the admin, and based on their response, the system upload the data or not to the database (im using Firebase and im using the table_calendar plugin).

And by the way, how i can make a custom notification about every event created by a same user, just like a reminder with sound.

I hope someone can help me because Is my first project in this lenguage.

Comment: For the notifications you will need Firebase Push Notifications, and the rest we would need more info to solve. You would probably save the event that your client created somewhere in Firestone, and when the admin confirms the request move it to a new collection of confirmed dates or something.

Comment: ok, maybe now I have a specific idea about how to do it, you think that's convenient to save the client event in a collection and send it to a waiting list where the admin can allow or delete it, and only the allowed events appear in the Interface?

Comment: I believe so. Another way that I didn't think of before would to be just have one collection, but have a flagged property like `isApproved`. Whenever the admin wants to approve requests you could just query the database to get documents that isApproved is false. Then if they approve change it to true and if not delete the document. Just another idea that might be easiser to implement. But I think you get the idea